# loop through two tables and print contents in order where id from each table matches each other

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have the following code which stores data from two mysql queries to cur and cur2:

```
for row in cur:
print("Series WFI - " + row[0] + " - " + row[1)

for fld in cur2:
    if fld[1] == row[0]:
        print(fld[4], fld[5)
```

What I am trying to do is loop through table 1 which has title/desc print this and then loop through table 2 and print the items if fld[1] equals row[0] (they are the same id). This works for the first record in table 1 but I am unable to get it to continue to loop and print table 2 contents under table 1 headers for the next id and so on.

**The following is the Actual result:**

Series WFI - AGM - Company Meeting

ElementName DataType
TableName   VarChar
Actflag Char
Created Date
Changed Date
*AGMID  Integer

Series WFI – AGNCY - Agency

Series WFI - AGYDT - Agency Details Change

**Expected result:**

Series WFI - AGM - Company Meeting

ElementName DataType
TableName   VarChar
Actflag Char
Created Date
Changed Date
AGMID   Integer

Series WFI – AGNCY

ElementName DataType
TableName   VarChar
Actflag Char
Created Date
Changed Date
AGNCYID Integer

Series WFI - AGYDT - Agency Details Change

ElementName DataType
TableName   VarChar
Actflag Char
Created Date
Changed Date
AGYDTID Integer

How can I get my code to print expected output? Thanks

Comment: Silly question, but why not write a SQL query that uses a JOIN? This would be far faster and it would let you use the database as a database 

Comment: move your second loop inside the first. However matigo's anwer is the most sensible way to follow.

Comment: I have also tried with 1 query joining both tables, table 1 has unique records all the titles and descriptions and table 2 has all the fields I want to poipulate that corresponds  to table 1 unique ids. All i want to do is to loop through table 1 print each record one by one with the fields from table 2 - but still having problems with my loops or i'm notr thinking of the correct logic here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the issue i had, having gone back to 1 table with a join in the mysql query and getting each unique id into a list and iterating through tweaking positioning of the print strings within the loop as follows:

```
unique = []
for id in cur:
    if id[0] not in unique:
        unique.append(id[0])
        print("Series WFI - " + id[0] + " - " + id[1])
    print(id[4], id[5])
```